# UIImageView inside UIScrollView Pans Too Far

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiscrollviewdelegate, ios6.0

I have a problem where I have a UIImageView inside a UIScrollView. In Interface Builder, the UIScrollView takes up the entire screen, and the UIImageView takes up the entire UIScrollView. The problem is that when I have an image that is landscape oriented I have it set to aspect fit, so I have gray bars at the top and bottom (which is what I want). However when I zoom into the photo, once the photo zooms large enough to fit the screen vertical I want it to not pan into the gray zone that was above it. See the screen shots I have attached. I basically want it to work like the Photos app in that respect. Here is my code for setting up the UIScrollView and UIImageView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0300.JPG"];
   self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
   self.scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
   self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.bounds.size;
   self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0;
   self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;
   self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;

}

-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   return self.imageView; 
}
```

[image: See how it pans too far up]

Thanks in advance.

Jacob

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is your whole `UIImageView` zoomed, not only its image, but also the gray bars. Your scrollView is just honestly reflecting this. The result you want probably can be done like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0300.JPG"];
    CGFloat ratio = CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.bounds) / image.size.width;
    self.imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.bounds), image.size.height * ratio);
    self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.scrollView.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.scrollView.bounds));
    self.imageView.image = image;
    self.scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.bounds.size;
    self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0;
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;

}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    UIView *subView = self.imageView;
    CGFloat offsetX = (scrollView.bounds.size.width > scrollView.contentSize.width)?
    (scrollView.bounds.size.width - scrollView.contentSize.width) * 0.5 : 0.0;

    CGFloat offsetY = (scrollView.bounds.size.height > scrollView.contentSize.height)?
    (scrollView.bounds.size.height - scrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.5 : 0.0;

    subView.center = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentSize.width * 0.5 + offsetX,
                                 scrollView.contentSize.height * 0.5 + offsetY);
}

-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.imageView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer is so good that I'd accept it twice if I could :)

Comment: I implemented your code and in viewDidAppear:animated the UIImageView bounds are back to the size declared in the storyboard. Do you have a clue to what can be triggering this?

Comment: @PedroBorges If you are using auto-layout, this code snippet may not work and you should use `NSLayoutConstraint` to update the size of the views. Or you can disable auto-layout in the storyboard to see whether everything works as your expect -- this may help you locate the issue.

Comment: Yes I understand that and yes I'm using auto layout but I have no constraints set for the UIImageView so why does it change size to match the containing UIScrollView?

Comment: @PedroBorges if you enabled auto-layout and haven't set constraints, they will be set automatically for you. Set frames or set constraints, they are exclusive.

Comment: Oh I see, but i can't even set constraints for an uiimageview inside a uiscrollview since the uiscrollview's contents are not fixed. In a nutshell maybe if i programmatically remove the "automatic" constraints!? or can i just disable auto layout in the uiimageview and keep the constraints for the uiscrollview to super and top/bottom guides?

Comment: @PedroBorges i will suggest that you disable auto-layout of the view of the `UIViewController` first to make sure it is the auto-layout that caused the issue.

Comment: That'll mess up the whole storyboard since I am using auto layout on each and every other view, gonna try through the constraints, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than "have gray bars at the top and bottom", set the background color of the `UIScrollView` to gray.

Also, don't use view dimensions in `viewDidLoad` as the subviews are not yet laid out. Move it to `didLayoutSubviews` or `viewWillAppear`. Also, set the `UIScrollView` `contentSize` based on your maximum zoom. For example:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];  // or other color
    CGFloat maxScale = 5.0;
    self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = maxScale;
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.bounds.size.width * maxScale, self.scrollView.bounds.size.height * maxScale); 
    self.scrollView.contentSize = contentSize;

    //  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIView *subView = self.imageView;
    CGFloat offsetX = (scrollView.bounds.size.width > scrollView.contentSize.width)?
    (scrollView.bounds.size.width - scrollView.contentSize.width) * 0.5 : 0.0;

    CGFloat offsetY = (scrollView.bounds.size.height > scrollView.contentSize.height)?
    (scrollView.bounds.size.height - scrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.5 : 0.0;

    subView.center = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentSize.width * 0.5 + offsetX,
                                 scrollView.contentSize.height * 0.5 + offsetY);
```